# Fourier transform's sine and cosine count as N grows

Tags: fourier-transform

I remember reading that in (discrete) Fourier transform for signals with even numbered N for length, the sine and cosine count is equal. Is this correct?

A bit of analysis:

N=1, there is only DC offset, which is a cosine wave of unlimited length.

N=2, Now, in addition to the DC offset term there is a other wave. But it's also a cosine wave, since trying to represent a sine with 2 points becomes impossible as only the 0 values of it can be sampled.

N=3, Sine can be represented as well as cos so there are 1 cos, 1 sine of same frequency and the DC offset cosine.

N=4, 3 cos, 1 sine, 3rd bin added with only cos wave possible.
...

So to me it seems that there are always going to be more cosine waves than sines. Did I make a mistake?

The interpretation that DC offset is a cosine could perhaps be debated though, has there ever been debate over this term? The fact that it surpasses the boundaries of N is a bit mind boggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the rfft is concerned (real-valued time domain), your analysis is not exact even tough you are not far. First you have to remember that `rfft(x) -> X` transforms the time domain discreet signal `x` to a frequency spectrum X composed of N/2+1 real values and N/2+1 imaginary values (for `N=len(x)`).

The only question here is how is it possible to create information from nothing (`N/2+1 + N/2+1 = N+2` not `N`). The answer is that you don't and you already discussed the reason:

- N=1: only the DC offset as you said, so it is defined for cosine but it is not for sine (since `ci1/N * sin(k*0) = 0`). So ci1, the corresponding coefficient in Fourier space is set to 0. In other words, here is one point here conveying no information.
- N=2: you are actually wrong on this one. Just try it. The 0 values are not the only one that can be sampled, so ci2 conveys information.
- N=N/2+1: this is the missing piece of the fake information creation. Because of symmetry, if N is even, the Fourier coefficient should be real ("giving" a "pure" cosine) removing another piece of meaningful information so that none is ultimately created. If it is odd, the coefficient should be complex without any other restriction.

So, yes, in some case there are more cosine than sine. But as stated otherwise, this is not conceptually important nor unsettling. On the contrary...

You were talking about odd functions, how is the DC component only odd or even? And in the end, the choice of an extra odd/even function depends only on the number of original points. :)

---

**Edit:** for me `N` was a number of components, *not* the number of samples!

Then yes: for `N=2`, you've got a real-valued `rfft` because of what you explained. However, this is not actually a property of the second bin of your `rfft`, this is a property of the *last* bin (if `N` is even).

So for N=2, two real numbers, for N=3, two real numbers and one imaginary, for N=4, 3 real numbers and 1 imaginary, for N=5, 3 real numbers and 2 imaginary and so one.

Comment: Just to clarify by n=2 example I meant that the sine part has to be 0, in other words the magnitude of frequency 1 can be anything, but the phase is always 0. The sine portion aliases to dc offset.
DC offset is viewed to be a cosine wave that is infinitely long, since that is the only way to build a straight line the length of the period out of sinusoidal functions. In the complex representation that would be a real valued exponential. I think the interpretation is a bit mysterious given that a sinusoid that doesn't reach the end of the cycle in the whole period is not a sinusoid at all really

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were taking an infinite signal and were reasoning about the value of each component.

Comment: I updated my answer..

Answer (score 0):

There is no Cos and Sine. There are frequencies that represent the original signal starting with 0 rate (DC), one cycle per the N points, 2 cycles per the N points... and so on. Depends of the actual best frequency estimator of the signal the pahse of the signal is determined.

Comment: Instead of calling the components cosine and sine, one could rephrase and ask whether there are more possibilities for the best fit estimators to be even functions rather than an odd functions.

Comment: Than it is not a Fourier Transform

Comment: @Moti But you can describe those cycles / possible phase relationships as cosines and sines. Right?

Comment: Referring to sine cosine is just a phase difference of $\pi/2$. Each bin in the transform is related to a different frequency in each the "sine" and "cosine" are the two component for each frequency that define the phase. I think that looking at it this way allow for better understanding of the meaning of the transformation as a means to look at a certain measurement from a different perspective and gain more insight into the information carried by those measurements.